# Jsop select has no result

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a string in initial html document like this:

```
<div data-qa="vacancy-serp__vacancy" class="vacancy-serp-item ">
```

When I am trying to select this by query [data-qa='vacancy-serp__vacancy'],

```
Elements elements = document.select("[data-qa='vacancy-
serp__vacancy']");
```

I have empty list:

```
System.out.println("Size is  " + elements.size());
Size is  0
```

But I have a positive result on https://try.jsoup.org/

Everything is okay with document (it has proper html code)

So, what is the problem ?  Thank you.

UPDATE!

I've just fixed it!

Problem was about version of jsoup (I've changed it from 1.8.3 to 1.11.2).
Now it works. Just fo the understanding - 1.8.3 is not for using anymore ?

Comment: can you post your HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

Replace ' with \"
It should work perfectly with any version

**Before**

```
Elements elements = doc.select("[data-qa='vacancy-serp__vacancy']");
```

**After**

```
Elements elements = doc.select("[data-qa=\"vacancy-serp__vacancy\"]");
```